# call method1 from method2 which are in same controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

Is there any way to do call `method1` from `method2` which are in the same controller. I tried to do that with the "this" keyword but it does not seems to work. I know that common code should be kept in the helper method but want to try this stuff.

```
({
bar : function(component, event, helper) {
       this.foo(); // it does not work. Error:- Cannot read property 'foo' of undefined]]
},
foo : function() {
     console.log('foo called');
}
 })
```

Comment: Check out this Q/A http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/55459/how-to-call-one-controller-function-from-another-controller-function-in-lightnin

Comment: Thanks Benahm. The solution which has been provided there is:- 

    var action = component.get("c.bar");
    action.$meth$();

    can you please explain action.$meth$(); I did not get it.

Comment: from the name you can see that it's an internal function to the Aura framework,  so follow the framework and use the helper....

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Short answer is No. Methods in the same controller cannot talk to each other because `this` will always be `undefined` in the controller. You need to use the `helper` for this case. Look at the [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/55512/20830) by Doug.

Although there's a way this can be done using `aura:method`, see [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/150222/20830). I would strongly recommend you to use `helper` instead of `aura:method`.

Comment: Thanks Praveen for the detailed explanation. As you said "Methods in the same controller cannot talk to each other because this will always be undefined in the controller". Can you please explain why it will be always "undefined",  is there any specific reason for this kind of behavior?

Comment: I believe this due the way in which the methods are wrapped in controller.js under [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, We can call the controller method inSide controller. See below code and try.

```
({
    handleButtonClick : function(component, event, helper) {
      console.log('handleButtonClick called !!!!!!');
      let secondAction = component.get('c.hanndleButtonClickSecond');
      $A.enqueueAction(secondAction);  
    },
    
    hanndleButtonClickSecond: function (cmp,event,helper){
        alert('handleButtonClickSecond Called successfully!!!!!!!!');
    }
})
```