# Need to show two dropdown in lightning using lightning select(Issue I am getting Object name but on selectin of object getting error)

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system

First Drop down in Object and second is Fields
On select of first drop down that is object i need to show related field in second drop down.

Code is below.
Component

```
<aura:component controller="QueryBuilderLightning" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" 
            access="global" >
<aura:attribute name="options" type="List" /> <!--object name list-->
<aura:attribute name="ObjectName" type="String" />
<aura:attribute name="selectedValue" type="String" />
<aura:attribute name="getField" type="List"/>     <!--Field name list-->
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
<lightning:select name="Objects" label="Select object:" aura:id="onjId" onchange="{!c.onChange}" value="{!v.selectedValue}">
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.options}" var="objectname">
        <option value="{!objectname}" text="{!objectname}" />  
    </aura:iteration>
</lightning:select>
<lightning:layoutItem size="12" padding="around-small">
    <lightning:select name="dependentFld"
                      value=""
                      label="Fields">
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.getField}" var="val">
            <option value="{!val}">{!val}</option>
        </aura:iteration>
    </lightning:select>
</lightning:layoutItem>
</aura:component>
```

Contoller

```
({
init: function(component, event, helper) {
var action = component.get("c.getObjectName"); //get apex method for object name
action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
    var state = response.getState();
    if (state === "SUCCESS") {           
        var allValues = response.getReturnValue();
        component.set("v.options", allValues);
    }                    
    else if (state === "ERROR") {
        var errors = response.getError();
        if (errors) {
            if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                console.log("Error message: " + 
                         errors[0].message);
            }
        } 
        else {
            console.log("Unknown Error");
        }
    }
});
$A.enqueueAction(action);
},
onChange: function(component, event, helper){
    var ObjectField = component.get("v.selectedValue");
       captureObjectField(component,ObjectField);
},

captureObjectField: function (component,ObjectField) {
    var objName = component.get("c.getObjectField"); //get apex method for field names
action.setParams({"objectName": objName});
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
    var state = response.getState();
    if (state === "SUCCESS") {           
        var allValues = response.getReturnValue();
        component.set("v.getField", allValues);

    }                    
    else if (state === "ERROR") {
        var errors = response.getError();
        if (errors) {
            if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                console.log("Error message: " + 
                         errors[0].message);
            }
        } 
        else {
            console.log("Unknown Error");
        }
    }
});
$A.enqueueAction(action);     
}
})


-------------------------------------------
**Apex class**
public class QueryBuilderLightning {
@AuraEnabled
public static List<String> getObjectName(){
    List<String> objects=new List<String>();
    List<Schema.SObjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().Values();  
    for(SObjectType sot:gd){
        objects.add(sot.getDescribe().getName());
        objects.sort();  
    }
    return objects;
}
@AuraEnabled
public static List<String> getObjectField(string objectName){
    Map <String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
    List<string> fieldsNames = new list<string>();
    
    Map <String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = 
 schemaMap.get(objectName).getDescribe().fields.getMap();
    for(Schema.SObjectField sfield : fieldMap.Values())
    {
        schema.describefieldresult dfield = sfield.getDescribe();
        fieldsNames.add(dfield.getLabel ());
        
    }
    return fieldsNames;
 }
 
}
Error
```

[image]

Modiifed Code

```
({
init: function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.getObjectName"); //get apex method for object name
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {           
            var allValues = response.getReturnValue();
            component.set("v.options", allValues);
        }                    
        else if (state === "ERROR") {
            var errors = response.getError();
            if (errors) {
                if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                    console.log("Error message: " + 
                                errors[0].message);
                }
            } 
            else {
                console.log("Unknown Error");
            }
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
onChange: function(component, event, helper){
    var ObjectField = component.get("v.selectedValue");
    var a = component.get("c.captureObjectField");
    $A.enqueueAction(a);    
},
captureObjectField: function (component,event,helper) {
    var objName = component.get("c.getObjectField"); //get apex method for field names
    var av = component.get("v.selectedValue");
    console.log(av);
    action.setParams({"objectName": av});
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {           
            var allValues = response.getReturnValue();
            console.log(allValues);
            component.set("v.getField", allValues);
            
        }                    
        else if (state === "ERROR") {
            var errors = response.getError();
            if (errors) {
                if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                    console.log("Error message: " + 
                                errors[0].message);
                }
            } 
            else {
                console.log("Unknown Error");
            }
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);     
}
```

})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting the error because you are calling the controller method inside another controller method in wrong way. Hence you are getting the error. The correct way is

```
({
    onChange : function(component, event, helper) {
        var a = component.get('c.captureObjectField');
        $A.enqueueAction(a);
    },
    captureObjectField : function(component, event, helper) {
        //do something
        //to get the value of object selected use component.find('onjId').get('v.value') as you have stored it in attribute
    }
})
```

read more here:- [Call another method from a method in same Lightning controller](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/172442/call-another-method-from-a-method-in-same-lightning-controller)

Comment: I have edited a code and now error gone ..but second drop down is not populating.

Comment: Apex method is not getting called from onChange -->captureObjectField controller method

Comment: change your line var av = component.get("v.selectedValue"); to var av = component.find('onjId').get('v.value'); it should work then

Comment: i am getting value in  captureObjectField: function (component,event,helper) {
        var objName = component.get("c.getObjectField"); //get apex method for field names
        var av=component.find('onjId').get('v.value');

        console.log('object-->'+av);

Comment: In console ..Getting value of object................. but not apex method is getting called.

Comment: You can accept this as a answer and open a new question by posting your apex class and highlighting the issue since the primary problem has been solved.

Comment: i have accepted an answer,and found the issue as well .thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error message says `captureObjectField is not defined`

You cannot directly call a controller method from another controller method.

Move **captureObjectField** to helper and it should work.

**controller.js**

```
({
    onChange: function (component, event, helper) {
        helper.captureObjectField(component);
    }
})
```

**helper.js**

```
({

    captureObjectField: function (component) {
        const objName = component.get("c.getObjectField"); //get apex method for field names
        // do your thing
    }
})
```